# Meaning of 'let it happen'

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was wondering about the meaning of 'let it happen' after reading a comment on [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5o5uZs0KKwY). (The video is about a leopard hunting a warthog. It is trying to kill the warthog by biting its throat.)

> The leopard like just let it happen' just let it happen. Go to
> sleep!!! It's bedtime!!!  LMFAO!!!

I did some research on the meaning of it.

From [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=let%20it%20happen):

> The phrase "Let it happen" can often be used in a situation where
> someone may be trying to force something e.g. relationships,
> conversations, sexual encounters, sports, image, ect.

With the definition, I catch that 'let it happen' has the meaning of enforcement. You want to overcome difficulty.

But [this article](https://medium.com/@BStulberg/letting-it-happen-versus-making-it-happen-9bd5eb7ee5b) from Medium uses the phrase to contrast with 'make it happen'. With the article, I feel 'let it happen' is similar as 'let it be'. It's not to force something but we observe as it goes without effort.

So I feel two articles are saying something contradictory. What's the meaning of 'let it happen'?

Comment: let is to allow. allow it to happen. Don't interfere with it. It has nothing at all to do with enforcement. If the leopard let something happen, we don't know what it is because you did not provide the context. And I don't feel like looking at a video to find out. let it happen=don't fight it. Accept whatever the thing is.

Comment: Urban Dictionary is notoriously unreliable. I think what they are trying to say is that "Let it happen" means "_Don't_ try to force something, just let the situation develop naturally". But I'm not sure what the comment on the video means.

Comment: You misunderstood the Urban Dictionary entry.  "Let it happen" can imply either "don't force it" or "don't resist it", with a literal meaning closer to "don't take any action".  The Urban Dictionary entry means "don't force it; let it happen naturally", as a *response* to someone trying too hard.  The Medium article explains that same meaning.  In contrast, the YouTube comment means "don't resist; the outcome is inevitable", and it's expressed from the viewpoint of the leopard.